# Expected Value of Infimum of Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, binomial-distribution

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})$ a probability space, consider a succesion of Bernoulli i.i.d. r.v with parameter $\theta=0.52$
I want to compute the expected value of $T(\omega)$ , where $T(\omega)$={$inf$ $0\leq n$, $X_n=1$}

I known by elemental probability that the succesion of Bernoullis is a Binomial(n,p) but the part of the infimum confuse me a bit.
Anny suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: $$\mathbb{E}(\tau) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}(\tau = k)$$

And for $\{\tau = k\} = \{X_1 = 0, \ldots,X_{k-1} = 0, X_k = 1\}$

Comment: $\mathcal(E) = n\cdot(1 - \sum_{i=1}^N p(1-p)^{i-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^N i\cdot p(1-p)^{i-1}$ So it would be something like this

Comment: I ended up with $\begin{align*}
E_1 &= \sum_{k \geq 1} k\ \mathrm{Pr}(\text{exactly } k \text{ trials for } 1 \text{ success}) \\
&= \sum_{k \geq 1} kq^{k-1}p \\
&= p(1-q)^{-2} & \text{provided } 0\leq q<1\\
&= p^{-1}
\end{align*}$

Comment: @AlonsoRangel so I guess that's the answer